# How do I attribute an interface to a class in Visio UML model

Tags: visio, uml

I have created a UML model in Visio 2010.  I have created several classes and interfaces.  In the UML model, how do I configure one of my classes to implement one of my interfaces?  In other words, how do I configure interface realization on one of my classes in the model?  I can show the realization in a class diagram by connecting the interface lollipop to the class but this does not help establish the realization in the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

According to this SuperUser answer : https://superuser.com/questions/240098/microsoft-visio-2010-umlclass-interfaces

> Open Model Explorer toolbar (if it isn't already open) and you'll see
>   your interface there. Drag it again to the page and connect to the new
>   class.

Answer (score -1):

This was super helpful. In addition, I right clicked and selected "Show as Class-like Interface" to display the Open Triangle-type arrow and dotted line to the interface object in my diagram

Comment: If an answer is super helpful, upvote the answer. Posting something like this just gets downvoted+deleted, helping nobody.

Comment: Hi David, I did upvote, but since I do not yet have a reputation score of 15, it will not display.  I felt my comment added good information on how to display the inheritance arrow.  My bad, I am new to contributing here.